# Which AWS service should be used for storing log4j logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, log4j

(Please feel free to mark this question as duplicate and share pointer to duplicates.)

Hi,

We are developing spring boot based application and will be using docker in production.

Currently it is using MongoDB (Atlas) for storing its log.  Looks like MongoDB Cloud will be expensive option to store logs/audit trails.

Since we are going to use AWS, which AWS service we should use to store Log4J Logs and audit messages?

Answer (score 1):

Usually people do store logs in s3, where you can archive logs with a combination of infrequent access and glacier for a reasonable money and you can apply also some life-cycle policy so the logs are automatically removed after a defined amount of time.

If you are looking for some kind of streaming/logging over a network, you may start with some AWS Lambda functions or SQS or you may want to go with some kind of service like https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/ if you believe that you are really big.

The other advantage of S3 (beside the lowest price) is that most of the other services support reading data from S3. So if you decide later that you want to analyze data with ElasticSearch or Elastic Map-Reduce cluster you will probably have some way how to do it.